# Who is the male investigator on the cover of Arkham Horror, Elder Sign, and Eldritch Horror?

Tags: arkham-horror, elder-sign, eldritch-horror

The 30- or 40-something dark-haired male on the cover of these games appears to be the same character, but it's not clear to me which. Is it one of the in-game characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly, I think it's just 'Generic 1920's stereotype'.  While I agree that he's got a tommy gun in both pictures, his facial structure looks wrong for being Michael McGlen.  He actually looks closer to Joe Diamond, if it wasn't for Joe Diamond having a blue suit.  Michael McGlen would be closest, without going over, but I think the cover art characters are just generic characters and no actual investigator.

Comment: I figured this to be likely, but the fact that the male character appears to clearly be the same specific person in all 3 games just made me wonder if this was a reference to another non-playable character or even someone from Lovecraft's writings or other reference (since I am new to the genre).

Comment: There's around 50 investigators in Arkham Horror, once you get all the expansions.  And since the game is out in it's entirety, I'd say it's likely Generic Male Protagonist.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, it would be [**Michael McGlen**](http://www.arkhamhorrorwiki.com/Michael_McGlen) due to the fact that he is rocking a tommygun.